# Update LWC field from future/queuable Apex

Tags: lightning-web-components, metadata-api, lwc-wire-adapter, empapi

I have something here which I thought would be simple but is turning out to be a nightmare. I've created an LWC Setup page where a user can create an Account (it's nothing more than an input field and a button) and then have the output of that Account create update a field on the LWC.  The workflow is this:

1. The user enters an Account name
2. The user clicks the button to submit it to an Apex controller method
3. The method creates the account
4. The id of the new Account is saved to a field on a Custom Metadata Type (via Metadata API)

The desired result is that a field on the LWC is updated when the Id is saved to the MDT.  I learned pretty quickly this is not as simple as it would seem.  This is what I've done so far (I'll try and be concise):

First, I have to use the Metadata API to update the MDT.  Ok, but I found that I can't call Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment to update the MDT record AFTER I've just created the Account, I get the MIXED_DML_OPERATION error.  Fine.  So I wrapped enqueueDeployment inside a future method (which I think is kind of weird since we're wrapping a queueable method inside an async method... whatever) and this worked to get my data saved.  I have this now for the Apex controller:

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Boolean createAccount(String name) {
        Account a = new Account(
            Name = name
        );
        Database.SaveResult insertResult = Database.insert(a);
        if (!insertResult.success) {
            return false;
        }

        insertMetadata(a.Id);

        return true;
    }

    @future
    private static void insertMetadata(Id id) {
            Metadata.CustomMetadata mdtConfig = new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
            mdtConfig.fullName = 'My_Custom_Metadata_Type__mdt.Account_Configuration';
            mdtConfig.label = 'Account Configuration';

            Metadata.CustomMetadataValue mdtVal = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
            mdtVal.field = 'Account_Id__c';
            mdtVal.value = String.valueOf(id);
            mdtConfig.values.add(mdtVal);

            Metadata.DeployContainer mdtContainer = new Metadata.DeployContainer();
            mdtContainer.addMetadata(mdtConfig);

            CustomMetaDataCallback callback = new CustomMetadataCallback();
            
            Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(mdtContainer, callback);
    }
```

And the definition for my DeploymentCallback:

```
public class CustomMetadataCallback implements Metadata.DeployCallback {

    public void handleResult(Metadata.DeployResult result, Metadata.DeployCallbackContext context) {
        System.debug('Result Status: ' + result.status.name());

        if (result.status == Metadata.DeployStatus.SUCCEEDED) {
            System.debug('CALLBACK SUCCEEDED');
        } else {
            System.debug('CALLBACK FAILED:');
            for (Metadata.DeployMessage msg : result.details.componentFailures) {
                System.debug('problemType: ' + msg.problemType);
                System.debug('problem: ' + msg.problem);
            }
            // TODO: permanently log this
        }
    }
}
```

This actually works well and the new Account Id is being saved to the MDT field.  Only now I'm so far removed from the original transaction that I don't know how to update the field in the LWC.  Here's what I've tried:

1. I originally had a wire defined to get the Account id:

```
    @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
    public static Account getAccount() {
        Account a;

        ... some code here to determine if the Account was already created

        if (needToDoLookup) {
            a = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id=:id.valueOf(accountId) LIMIT 1];
        }

        return a;
    }
```

I added this as a wired method in my component and supplemented with a call to refreshApex:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import getAccount from '@salesforce/apex/CustomMetadataController.getAccount';
import createAccount from '@salesforce/apex/CustomMetadataController.createAccount';

export default class CustomSetup extends LightningElement {

    accountId;
    accountName;

    wiredGetAccountResult;

    @wire(getAccount)
    wiredGetAccount(result => {
        this.wiredGetAccountResult = result;
        if (result) {
           ...
        } else {
           ...
        }
    )}

    handleButtonClick(evt) {
        createAccount( {name: this.aName } )
        .then(() => {
            this.getAccountId();
            refreshApex(this.wiredGetAccountResult);
        });
    }

    get aName() {
        let retval = '';
        let acctname = this.template.querySelector("[data-id='accountName']");
        if (acctname) { retval = acctname.value; }
        return retval;
    }
}
```

This did not work at all.  Despite the fact that the MDT field was updated the wire function never fired.

2. I then tried to brute-force the process by wrapping getAccount inside a Promise and then calling that a set number of times to wait out when the MDT is updated.

```
    maxRetries = 5;

    renderedCallback() {
        if (!this.isRendered) {
            this.getAccountId(1); // only need to do once here
            this.isRendered = true;
        }
    }

    getAccountId(numRetries) {
        let timeoutVal = 1000;
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                getAccount()
                .then(result => {
                    numRetries--;
                    if (result) {
                        this.accountId = result.Id;
                        this.accountName = result.Name;
                        console.log('stop here');
                        resolve();
                    } else if (numRetries > 0) {
                        this.getAccountId(numRetries);
                    } else {
                        resolve();
                    }
                });
            }, timeoutVal);
        })
    }

    handleButtonClick(evt) {
        createAccount( {name: this.aName } )
        .then(() => {
            this.getAccountId(this.maxRetries);
        });
    }

    get aName() {
        let retval = '';
        let acctname = this.template.querySelector("[data-id='accountName']");
        if (acctname) { retval = acctname.value; }
        return retval;
    }
```

This doesn't always work, though, if the call to enqueueDeployment ends up taking more than 5 seconds (and I don't want the UI to sit and hang forever).  In my scratch org I've seen it take up to 2 minutes sometimes before the queued method returns so I don't have any confidence that this is going to be reliable in production.

3. I tried using lightning/empApi to subscribe to changes to the My_Custom_Metadata_Type__mdt object itself.

```
...
import { subscribe, unsubscribe, onError, setDebugFlag, isEmpEnabled } from 'lightning/empApi';
...

export default class CustomSetup extends LightningElement {

    channelName = '/data/My_Custom_Metadata_Type__ChangeEvent';

    subscription = {};

    accountId;
    accountName;
    isRendered = false;

    maxRetries = 5;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.handleSubscribe();
        this.registerErrorListener();
    }

    // Handles subscribe button click
    handleSubscribe() {
        // Callback invoked whenever a new event message is received
        const messageCallback = function(response) {
            console.log('New message received: ', JSON.stringify(response));
            // Response contains the payload of the new message received
        };

        // Invoke subscribe method of empApi. Pass reference to messageCallback
        subscribe(this.channelName, -1, messageCallback).then(response => {
            // Response contains the subscription information on subscribe call
            console.log('Subscription request sent to: ', JSON.stringify(response.channel));
            this.subscription = response;
        });
    }

    ...

    registerErrorListener() {
        // Invoke onError empApi method
        onError(error => {
            console.log('Received error from server: ', JSON.stringify(error));
            // Error contains the server-side error
        });
    }
}
```

This doesn't work either, I get the error `The channel specified is not valid {/data/My_Custom_Metadata_Type__ChangeEvent}`.  I've also tried /data/My_Custom_Metadata_Type__mdt__ChangeEvent but this also didn't work, unsurprisingly.  Does empApi even work with MDT?  I don't see any documentation that states it doesn't but it certainly doesn't act like it does.

I'm out of ideas on what to do here.  If you've read this far and you have ideas or see something that I'm doing wrong I'd love to hear about it.  Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: You need to publish your own platform event (see referenced answer) and stop (ab)using MDTs. Use a vanilla custom object to store your state.

Comment: @identigral, thanks for the quick response.  Yes, the link does give me a direction I hadn't considered so thank you for that.  Regarding the use of MDT; I'm not using the MDT to store transient data.  This is a configuration step so the end user needs to supply information we can't possibly install.  It's a set-it-and-forget-it step, we're providing a setup tab for convenience.  We use MDT because it's cached and free to query.  I don't believe we're using this in an incorrect context.

Comment: Based on your info, it sounds like MDT  was selected because its cached and free to query. However, is that benefit worth the cons you've noted? Since you used MDT you had to embark on this long process to hit the Metadata API and go to queueable whereas a custom object or custom setting would've just been a simple DML and seems to meet the need (even if it's a set it and forget it record). MDT is more for "static" mappings/settings/configuration you can supply. The fact it's not easily updateable/creatable in apex is probably not by accident

Comment: @KrisGoncalves, thanks for the feedback.  No, those aren't all the reasons entirely.  I guess I didn't intend for this to be a discussion on why we're using MDTs.  Suffice it to say that when we started on this project the data that was stored in our MDTs was not intended to be mutable via code.  In the past week that requirement has changed and I admit that I'm still green enough that I didn't know to push back on it.  And here we are.    I'm getting a better understanding of all this now.  I do appreciate everyone's comments as I did learn quite a bit today, which is what this is all about.

Comment: That's understandable - I think @identigral's link is a good question/answer for the question you actually asked (handling long running transaction) but it's always important to see if this is an [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and it does seem your new use case may end up having you re-evaluate some previous choice(s)

Comment: @identigral - The link you provided is indeed useful and I can use it for other things.  Please post your response as an answer so I can give you the credit.